# How can i add cell to UITableView Section with core data saved info

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have a UITableView whit 3 sections, i have 3 tables for each section, i use 3 popUps to fill the tables(Formula, Time, Step) for each section at this point everything works fine

```
var sections : [String] = []
var buttons : [Int] = []

sections = [" Formula:", " Time:", " Steps: "]
buttons = [1,2,3]

var formula : [Formula] = []
var time : [Time] = []
var step : [Step] = []

var fetchReultFormula : NSFetchedResultsController<Formula>!
var fetchResultTime : NSFetchedResultsController<Time>!
var fetchResultStep : NSFetchedResultsController<Step>!
```

On tableView section of code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section]
    }

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return formula.count
        case 1:
            return time.count
        default:
            return step.count
        }
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell :UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "mycell")

        switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            let result = formula[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = result.ing
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(result.cant) grs"
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: result.type!)
        case 1:
            let result = [indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = result.name
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(resultado.min) min"
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "time")
        default:
            let result = step[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = result.desc
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "check")
        }
        return cell
    }
```

When i add record to any table trough popUpView how can i add this record to respective section when dismiss the popUpView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result of our comments, lets go with delegation to see if we can solve your problem:

Declare a protocol, you can do it in another file or in your `ViewController`:

This protocol has a method to fetch data again after you add data in `FormulaViewController`

```
protocol DataFetcherDelegate {
    func fetchData()
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {
```

Then conform to this protocol from your `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, DataFetcherDelegate {
```

After you conform to the protocol, you are gonna have to implement `fetchData` method inside `ViewController`, this is where you are gonna put core data fetch request to get up to date data:

```
func fetchData() {
    print("fetchingData")
    // write your data fetching code here, then make your arrays equal respectively again.
    // once fetching and assigning data to arrays are complete do:
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Now go to `FormulaViewController` and add a `delegate` variable like following:

```
class FormulaViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: DataFetcherDelegate?
```

Go back to `ViewController` then, where ever you are instantiating your `FormulaViewController` (I obtained the code below from your comment, you need to cast the VC as `FormulaViewController` as well, it is a bit updated don't use your old code) and assign `ViewController` as the `delegate` of `FormulaViewController`:

```
let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "formulaView") as! FormulaViewController
vc.delegate = self // assigning self as delegate of FormulaVC
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now we are done with `ViewController` part, we will go to `FormulaViewController` now and do the following:

Before you dismiss your popupView after saving new data successfully, now we are gonna tell our `delegate` (`ViewController`) to fetch core data again then we will dismiss `FormulaViewController`:

```
//save your respective item to your core data, formula, time or step

// then for the sake of example, lets add a Formula:

let newFormula = Formula(/*with your core data context*/)
//save to your core data with context. like persistentContainer.viewContext.save(), I dont know how you implemented that.
delegate?.fetchData()
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now hopefully once the `FormulaViewController` is dismissed, the data of `ViewController` will be updated as well.

Comment: I apreciate your help. i am new on swift i call the popup with let vc : UIViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "formulaView") and self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil) from ViewController.swift and dismiss on FormulaViewController.swift after save data. How can i know what table have the new record on ViewController.swift and how can i add a row with this new record on tableView.

Comment: You need to use delegation pattern, with that pattern you are going to be able to fire some functions of your base ViewController, from FormulaViewController. Make some research about how to do that, if you cant. I will try to help you out with that.

Comment: Please help me, i really new on swift, i will apreciate so much

Comment: Before we go with delegation, can you try fetching coreData in viewWillAppear of ViewController? This way, you save your data in FormulaViewController, then dismiss it. When you dismiss it, ViewController's view will appear again, then you should fetch core data and after fetch complete and all data arrays are deployed with recent data, do `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: I did it, in fact i put a print statement to send a message to console log when viewWillAppear execute but only the first time occurs, when i dismiss the popup viewController nothing occurs. :(

Comment: I see, I tried to implement delegation for you. Please check the answer. Make sure your pop up view controller is called FormulaViewController, or update my answer while using.

Comment: well, i did it too, the delegation works fine but still without add cell to table view section. I will apreciate if you may help me a little bit more when you can. I put the code here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5ewr2czr9x6dall/AAB3DJxQ-Dj3_Nuet4ucq1c4a?dl=0. Again thank you so much.

Comment: I looked at your code, you forgot to put `tableView.reloadData()` in your fetchData() method. at the end of do-catch, put it. It should work fine